# Display value not key of list after loading of node

Tags: theming

I've created a controller and I'm loading a node.

```
$variables['contest'] = Node::load(12);

return [
    '#theme' => 'theme_contest',
    '#variables' => $variables,
];
```

In this node there is a field "field_contest_things" of type list (text):

```
0|Dance
1|Read
2|Playing
```

In the twig file if I'm doing

```
{{ variables['contest'].field_contest_things.value }}
```

this will display the key and not the "value".

Is there any way that I can display the value and not the key in the twig ? Or should I change something in my controller ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your field allows only 1 value, you can do it in both ways, i.e Controller or Twig :

**Controller**

```
$node->field_contest_things->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('allowed_values')[$node>field_contest_things->value];
```

**Twig**

```
{{ node.field_contest_things.fieldDefinition.settings['allowed_values'][node.field_contest_things.value] }}
```

*Update*

You can now skip the usage of `fieldDefinition` on the latests Drupal 8 updates:

```
{{ node.field_contest_things.setting('allowed_values')[node.field_contest_things.value] }}
```

---

By experience, I suggest you to move for a taxonomy if you need to query your node by this field value on the future. It's more maintainable & scalable.

---

Hope it helps you !